# Modern Warfare 2 Connecting to Servers Take 15 Mins

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I just started to play Modern Warfare 2 and I notice it takes me about 15 minutes in order to connect to a server.  I open all the router ports, defrag game files from steam, and troubleshoot to the best to my knowledge, but still no luck. Any one else have any ideas?

Comment: I've gotten this too, it seemed to help when I created a custom game and then quit.

Comment: The game is dead.. Everyone moved to MW3, and there are no dedicated servers for MW2.

Comment: do you mean "15 mins to connect" or "15 mins to find a server which is not empty/not full/meets my filter criteria"

Comment: 15 mins to find a server and then after that I get in. If I back out and try again I get in instantly.

Comment: we're all sad about it

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a combination of factors but most likely:

- Hard-core COD players moving to the latest and greatest COD iteration
- Not having any map-packs installed

Both of which will reduce the pool of sessions you can join. It's particularly noticeable after new map packs come out as most of the regular player base will have brought them and therefor only be in sessions where all players have access to the same maps.

You don't mention where you are or what time you play. That might also have an effect on how many active games you are seeing.